# Pass Spring object to non Spring project

Tags: java, spring-mvc, ejb

I have a Spring MVC project in which a set of environment variables are read into a singleton class when the application is deployed and started.

```
@Component
@Scope("singleton")
public class EnvironmentConfiguration {
    ....
}
```

This works fine. However, I'm working on a non-Spring project consisting of a few EJBs which are used by the first (Spring) project. I'm wondering if I can read (consume) the singleton class in the non-Spring project.

It might be worth mentioning that within the Spring project, this class is used like:

```
@Autowired
private EnvironmentConfiguration environmentConfiguration;
```

Comment: Yes, your classes in Spring are typically POJOs, or "Plain Ol' Java Objects".  As such, they can be used in non-Spring-ified code just fine.  However, if you are including it as a library you will probably need to include the Spring JARs.  If you are using in the same "application", just part of it is not Spring, then you should be fine as-is.

Comment: Thanks. What I had in mind though was, beside the obvious way of passing the object (which requires Interface change), to use the class via Spring application's context. I don't mind adding a lean set of Spring dependencies to the second project.

Comment: If you are using the app context in the 2nd app, how are you going to do that without Spring?  Can you clarify a bit what you want to do, maybe give a very simple example in code?